# When retrieving passed arguments from a bundle, why does Android Studio warn and suggest using requireArguments() instead of arguments!!?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

So, like the title says I'm trying to retrieve passed arguments from a bundle according to the documentation I'm following by using `var args = GameWonFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!)`.
But Android Studio suggests using the following code:
`var args = GameWonFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())`

I looked up the Android Documentation for Fragment and found that `requireArguments()` returns a @NonNull Bundle or an IllegalStateException. Why does Android Studio suggest using it and what's the difference between the two?

Also, I couldn't find relevant documentation about `fromBundle()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some api changes in androidx.fragment:fragment

**requireArguments()** --- method which returns a @NonNull Bundle or throws an IllegalStateException.

fromBundle(arguments!!) --- these case App may be crashed because of Null pointer exception. if arguments is null app will be crashed.

Comment: Alright, thanks!
And wouldn't IllegalStateException lead to crashes too, so how is it any better?

Do you know of any documentation regarding ````fromBundle()````

Answer (score 4):

As per the `UseRequireInsteadOfGet` Lint warning:

> AndroidX added new "require____()" versions of common "get___()" APIs, such as getContext/getActivity/getArguments/etc. Rather than wrap these in something like  requireNotNull(), using these APIs will allow the underlying component to try to tell you *why* it was null, and thus yield a better error message.

Importantly, the error messages always mention **which fragment** caused the issue, including the class name of the Fragment and its unique ID. This can be particularly useful when correlating that ID with [Fragment's debug logging](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#enableDebugLogging(boolean)), thus allowing you to understand when that Fragment was first added or updated.